# How to prove the finiteness of lower semi-continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a convex set, and let $f$ be a lower semi-continuous convex function.
In addition, we have $f$ is bounded above on every bounded subset of $\text{ri}~C$,
where $\text{ri}~C$ is the relative interior of $C$.

I know that the $f$ may not be bounded above on the whole set $C$.
However, could i prove that $f$ is finite on $C$?

The definition of relative interior is 
\begin{equation}
\text{ri}~C = \{\boldsymbol{x} \in \text{aff}~C \mid \exists \varepsilon > 0, (\boldsymbol{x}+\varepsilon B) \cap (\text{aff}~C) \subset C\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: We need some more context here. What do you mean by a "finite" lsc convex function? Do you mean that it only takes values on $(-\infty, \infty)$? If so, then what do you mean $f$ is "finite on $C$"? I don't see what these terms could mean in any way that makes this question non-trivial.

Comment: Also, $C$ is convex, but where does it belong? Is it in a Euclidean space? Banach space? Normed linear space? Topological vector space? CAT[0] space?

Comment: I am sorry for my negligence. The finite means takes values on $(-\infty,+\infty)$.
The $f$ is finite on $C$ equals to $-\infty < f(x) < +\infty, \forall x \in C$.
In addition, $C$ is in a Euclidean space.

Comment: Then isn't this trivial? If $f$ is a finite function then $f$ is finite on $C$ (as well as outside of $C$, and everywhere else), right?

Comment: oh, sorry. I am a bit confused, causing me to write a extra ``finite''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is finite on $C$. Consider a point $x$ in the Euclidean space $X$ such that $f(x) = \infty$. By lower semi-continuity, there must be some open neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ around $x$ such that
$$y \in \mathcal{U} \implies f(y) \ge f(x) = \infty \implies f(y) = \infty.$$
If $x$ were in $C$, then the density of $\operatorname{ri} C$ in $C$ implies that $\operatorname{ri} C \cap \mathcal{U} \neq \emptyset$. This would imply the existence of a point in $\operatorname{ri} C$ where $f$ is infinite.